# What is the conjugation in the word 「起たんか」and what does it mean?

Tags: conjugations

The full sentence is「おい起【た】て。起【た】たんか」頭の所に立っていた伍長が怒鳴った。
This is older Japanese by the way, so 「起て」and 「起たんか」are pronounced 「たて」and「たたんか」。
Anyway, I was wondering what the conjugation in 「起【た】たんか」means. I'm guessing it's a command or something, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You can add the reading of a word in kanji as furigana by putting the hiragana reading between the characters【 】just right after the kanji. For example, 学校【 がっこう 】renders 学校【がっこう】.

Comment: thank you @jarmanso7. New to this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [起]{た}たんか
>   *Get up! / Stand up!*

It consists of: verb たつ + literary negative ん + question particle か

It's a literary version of [起]{た}たないか.

「～ないか。」 expresses (strong) command. From [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/162301/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%8B/):

> ないか
>   ［連語］《助動詞「ない」＋終助詞「か」》
>   ２ 命令の意を表す。「早くし**ないか**」「もたもたしないでさっさと歩か**ないか**」